# Shoutcast stream not playing with jPlayer

Tags: javascript, streaming, audio-streaming, jplayer, shoutcast

I am trying to stream my shoutcast url with jPlayer. I get it to work flawlessly with other shoutcast URLs, just the one I rquire is not working. In Chrome I get a request cancelled status message.

This is my working code for all other streams I found.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var stream = {
        title: "ABC Jazz",
        mp3: "http://80.237.158.41:8000/;"
    },
    ready = false;

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            ready = true;
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream);
        },
        pause: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");
        },
        error: function(event) {
            if(ready && event.jPlayer.error.type === $.jPlayer.error.URL_NOT_SET) {
                // Setup the media stream again and play it.
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", stream).jPlayer("play");
            }
        },
        swfPath: "../js/jplayer/",
        supplied: "mp3",
        preload: "none",
        wmode: "window",
        keyEnabled: true
    });

});
```

All of these streams work:

- 67.205.95.146:8068/;
- 77.68.106.224:8018/;

Except for this one:

- 80.237.158.41:8000/;

Does anybody have the slightest clue why it will be doing this?

Comment: Are you sure it's an MPEG stream? Flash cannot properly handle the ADTS stream that SHOUTcast AACP stations use.

Comment: Yes, its content-type is audio/mpeg. I have got it working with the exact same stream types as mentioned above. just the one I need doesnt want to play.??

Comment: Same problem, have you figured out something about this?

Comment: No Sandro, still stuck and havnt really worked on that further. Will post as soon a s a solution is found. Please let me know if you got it working aswell

Answer (score 1):

Try setting url to 
`http://80.237.158.41:8000/;*.nsv', type: 'mp3'` or just `http://80.237.158.41:8000/;*.nsv'`

It also works with all html5 and jplayers.